# Converting an arrays to an object without keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I am looking for a way to i convert this.

```
    const data = [{
                id: 1,
                fullnames: 'JosephSam',
                weight: 1231,
                currentdate: '2021-09-22'
    }]
```

into this

```
        const data = {
                id: 1,
                fullnames: 'JosephSam',
                weight: 1231,
                currentdate: '2021-09-22'
    }
```

Comment: The data that you want to convert is invalid. Array is a collection of values not collection of key-value pairs.

Comment: What are you going to do if there are multiple values in the array?

Comment: data is an array, You can use indexing `data[0]`

Comment: I don't get it. So take first object from the array? And what do you mean without keys? It's not possible, there will be always a key. Even for array there is one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple values inside your array, then you can have a separate object to insert each array value into it by having id as the object key.

Take a look at the following example.

```
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    fullnames: "JosephSam",
    weight: 1231,
    currentdate: "2021-09-22",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    fullnames: "Jane",
    weight: 1431,
    currentdate: "2021-09-22",
  },
];

const mappedData = {};

data.forEach((element) => (mappedData[element.id] = element));

console.log("Mapped Data: ", mappedData);
```

**Console log**

```
Mapped Data:  {
  '1': {
    id: 1,
    fullnames: 'JosephSam',
    weight: 1231,
    currentdate: '2021-09-22'
  },
  '2': { id: 2, fullnames: 'Jane', weight: 1431, currentdate: '2021-09-22' }
}
```

Then you can refer each element by id as follows. (`x` is the id you need to get)

```
mappedData[x]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr = [{
            id: 1,
            fullnames: 'JosephSam',
            weight: 1231,
            currentdate: '2021-09-22'
}];

const data = arr[0];

console.log(data.fullnames); // 'JosephSam'
```

This would be what you need.
I do get the feeling this is isn't what you're looking for.
If so, please give us a more complex example to see what it is you're dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you trying to do. But If you have a single indexed array you should to this:

```
var data = [{
    id: 1,
    fullnames: 'JosephSam',
    weight: 1231,
    currentdate: '2021-09-22'
}]
data = data[0];
```